# How can I see which applications have accessed a certain file within a given time period on Linux?

Tags: linux, files, audit, monitoring

Is it possible on Linux to find out which applications have accessed a certain file in the
last 24 hours?

I've come with a few possible solutions:

1. Watch `lsof`. It works, but it's constrained to watch's granularity.
2. `inotify` sounds good... but no information of the application accessing the file is provided.
3. `auditd` may be useful, but I haven't checked that yet.

What ways can I see which applications have accessed a certain file within a given time period?

Comment: I assume that you're using a posix operating system since you mention `lsof` and other utilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auditd` would be the way to go for this. [Here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html) a quick tutorial on how to accomplish monitoring a file. You'll have to setup a watch on the file beforehand though.